# Calcular diferencia de Años, mes y días entre fechas

Tags: java, android, date

Estoy intentando buscar o hacer una función en Java (Android Studio) que me diga la diferencia de años, mes y días entre dos fechas.
Por ejemplo:
25/03/2023 y 30/03/2023 (0 Años 0 Meses y 5 días)
25/03/2023 y 30/04/2023 (0 Años 1 Meses y 5 días)
25/03/2023 y 30/04/2024 (1 Años 1 Meses y 5 días)

Tengo realizado esto pero no está muy ajustado

```
public static String getDiferencia(Date fechaInicial, Date fechaFinal){

    long diferencia = fechaFinal.getTime() - fechaInicial.getTime();

    long diasMilli = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    //86.400.000

    long diasTranscurridos = (diferencia / diasMilli) % 30;

    long mesTranscurridos = (diferencia / diasMilli) / 30;

    long annoTranscurridos = mesTranscurridos / 12;

    mesTranscurridos = mesTranscurridos - annoTranscurridos * 12;
   
    return "Años : " + annoTranscurridos + "-- Meses : " + mesTranscurridos + "--  Dias: " + diasTranscurridos;
}
```

Pero no encuentro ninguna función o procedimiento:

Gracias.

Comment: Utiliza la librería localDateTime de java 8, es lo mas recomendable para operaciones de fechas

Comment: aqui tienes un enlace con algo de info al respecto para comparativa básica, para específicas puedes trabajar con instants o restando meses y dias https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/compare-localdatetime/

Answer (score 1):

**Obtener diferencia entre dos fechas**

Para calcular la diferencia puedes usar la clase [**Period**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) y su método **[between()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#between-java.time.LocalDate-java.time.LocalDate-)** :

```
 Period period = Period.between(localDatefirstDate, localDatesecondDate);
```

`period` obtendrá los valores de diferencia de años, meses y días entre las dos fechas

```
public static String getDiferencia(Date fechaInicial, Date fechaFinal){
    //Convierte Date a LocalDate, necesario para usar en función  Period.between()
    LocalDate localfirstDate = LocalDate.of(getYear(fechaInicial), getMonth(fechaInicial), getDay(fechaInicial));
    LocalDate localsecondDate = LocalDate.of(getYear(fechaFinal), getMonth(fechaFinal) , getDay(fechaFinal));
    //Obtiene diferencia 
    Period period = Period.between(localfirstDate, localsecondDate);
    return "Años : " + period.getYears() + "-- Meses : " + period.getMonths() + "--  Dias: " + period.getDays();
}
```

---

Ejemplo:

```
  //Define fecha inicial y final.
  Date fechaInicial = new GregorianCalendar(2023, Calendar.JUNE, 25).getTime();
  Date fechaFinal= new GregorianCalendar(2023, Calendar.JUNE, 30).getTime();

 
  //Llama función getDiferencia.
  System.out.println(getDiferencia(fechaInicial, fechaFinal));
```

Salida:

```
Años : 0-- Meses : 0--  Dias: 5
```